# How good is the noise reduction on an XRackpro2?

Tags: rack

Some manufacturers of soundproof rack equipment such as Kell Systems or Acoustirack do quote noise reduction figures but I can't find any specifications for an XRackPro2.  Given the evasive nature of the manufacturer's literature (they do everything but state noise reduction figures) and the somewhat somewhat narrower dimensions (61cm vs. 75cm) than the Kell Systems rack I'm inclined to simply dismiss it as probably not very good.  However, I need to get it up a stairway that might be too narrow to fit the Kell rack, so the Kell is looking like it's not a goer.

Does anyone have first hand experience of XRackPro racks?  The noisest things it will contain are disk arrays - an HP MSA30 and a Xyratex RS1600 (Same OEM as a NetApp DS14 but a different disk layout).  It needs to go next to somebody's desk, so it needs to be comfortably quiet, but it's not going into a recording studio.

Alternatively, does anyone have a recommendation for a 18-24U soundproof rack that is no more than 70cm or thereabouts wide?

Comment: Why is the stair width an obstacle?  The racks I've seen where shipped flat, and assembled on-site.

Comment: I don't think that this is the case with soundproof cabinets - the manufacturer's literature for various ones that I've looked at seems to imply that it isn't the case.

Comment: When we had our Kell Systems cabinet delivered it was already assembled.

Comment: Did you get the rack, and if so, how effective was it in noise reduction?

Comment: @ewwhite - No, I never got the rack.  I solved the noise problem with different hardware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have two 12U XRackPro2 racks, one in a lab space one in the vestibule of my office.  Both have less gear than what you're talking about (UPS, 1U Server, 12-15 drives, tape library) but I've been happy with their build quality and ability to isolate server noise. Mine are well tolerated by those who share a room with them and while they are much quieter than a regular rack, it's certainly not silent.  In my office, the heat output requires leaving the AC on almost all the time, which further increases the noise level. Since you'll have significantly more disks (more heat & noise) your exhaust fans will run more and make more noise trying to vent all that heat.

Seriously though, I'm glad there's no rack next to my desk, especially not a heat spewing SAN cabinet. It's not unbearable, but if you think the noise/heat is tolerable, put the rack next to your desk not someone else's.

Comment: How effective is the sound isolation/reduction?

Comment: I don't have a decibel meter, but it's done a great job at dampening the sound from my gear.  When it was in a normal Dell rack you could hear fans humming through my office door in the hallway and people would occasionally comment on the noise. Now no one notices the hum.

Answer (score 0):

I bought the 12U and I am disappointed. We just plugged the fan unit into an outlet, without any equipment in the rack. The fans are too noisy to be tolerated in an office. When I inquired about my options for returning the rack I got - you guessed it - crickets.